# How do I enable SQLite on Linux/Apache/PHP?

Tags: linux, php, php.ini, sqlite

To enable **SQLite** on my **Windows**/Apache/PHP setup, I uncomment the following lines in the **php.ini** file and restart Apache:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

Now I have a **VPS** with **Suse Linux 10.3** and **Apache/PHP** was set automatically. Looking through the **php.ini** file to make the above changes, I see that things are a little different on Linux:

- there is no list of extensions to uncomment
- I found "`extension_dir = /usr/lib/php5/extensions`" but in this directory find only:

  - pdo.so
  - pdo_mysql.so

**How can I enable SQLite in this Linux environment?**

Comment: here's a great tutorial on how to enble sqlite in a linkyx environment: http://www.exteon.ro/en/articles/php. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i cannot tell how exactly for suse this would work. in debian world it's:

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

this will install needed library and add /etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini with

```
extension=sqlite.so
```

so first - use yum to see install needed package, then add to php.ini line above.

**EDIT: for php7 the command is:**

```
apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
```

and php.ini file is located at: `sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` where you have to enable the `extension=sqlite.so`

Comment: apt-get seems to be a debian thing, there are workarounds (http://susewiki.org/index.php?title=Install-apt4suse) but I'm looking for the simplest solution here, there must be some way to just download and reference a sqlite library in Suse.

Comment: yum is the simple way

Comment: ok so I converted my VPS from Suse to Debian Linux 4.0 Standard 32-Bit. I type "apt-get install php5-sqlite" and it says "reading packge lists, building dependency tree...couldn't find package php5-sqlite". In /etc/php5/conf.d there are 8 other .ini files but not sqlite.ini.  How come it couldn't find the package do I need to run that from a specific directory? (I type "yum" and it says "-bash: yum: command not found".)

Comment: Debian uses apt-get, Suse offers yum (and maybe zypper). If apt-get can't find the package, check that it exists and check which repositories you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Comment: in /etc/apt/sources.list.d I have one file called "debian.list" but no others, can I just download the library from somewhere and reference it in php.ini as on Windows, or does it need to be downloaded and installed somehow?

Comment: @ Edward Tanguay add to your /etc/apt/sources at least "deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian/ lenny non-free main". then run "apt-get update" and then - try "apt-get install".  [ remove quotes ]

Comment: I had the same problem. Solve with this solution provided by @pQd

Answer (score 5):

Short version, but might be wrong because I don't know what package repositories your system is set up with:

```
yum install php5-sqlite
```

Long version:

```
yum search php sqlite
```

Or just search for one:

```
yum search sqlite
```

Look at the list that comes back.  Figure out what you need, then:

```
yum install whatever_package_looked_right_from_the_list
```

Comment: +1: whatever package looked right

Answer (score 1):

SQLite support is enabled by default on a standard Linux PHP compilation starting with PHP 5.0.

Which PHP version do you use? Did you checked the phpinfo() output to see if SQLite is enabled? SQLite will be enabled unless the

```
--disable-sqlite
```

parameter is set in configure string.

Answer (score 1):

Linux Mint 12 was missing sqlite and it was generating the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Best practise for me it was to [download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-updates/amd64/php5-sqlite/download) and unpack `sqlite.so` to `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/`

Comment: You can replace `natty` in the URL with your version's name, like `trusty`.