# What should I change in php.ini to enable usage of sqlite from PHP?

Tags: php, php.ini, sqlite

At the moment I cannot use sqlite from PHP. Probably I need to change something in my php.ini file. In my php.ini file I found 2 lines containing "sqlite":

```
[sqlite]
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0
```

Does semicolon in front of the line means that line is commented? Should I uncomment the second line? Should I change the value of the "sqlite.assoc_case" from 0 to something else?

P.S.
I have 2 php.ini files:

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

which one should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried my suggestion in [your other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/117610/why-class-sqlitedatabase-is-not-found-in-var-www-php) to install the php5-sqlite package?

What you're looking for in php.ini once this package is installed is a line similar to extension=sqlite.so (the module name may be slightly different.)

The options in the [sqlite] section just change the options when SQLite is in use correctly.

Yes a ; in front of a line is a comment.

The file you want to change is the one Apache is using (if you're using accessing your PHP script through a web browser.)

Comment: I just tried to install php5-sqlite and got the following: Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-sqlite3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package php5-sqlite3 has no installation candidate

Comment: I have installed php5-sqlite (not php5-sqlite3) and it worked. Thank you very much!