# How do I activate SQLite3 on PHP 5.3.3 Centos 5?

Tags: php, centos5, php.ini, sqlite

I have reviewed the previous questions on this and they don't seem to cover what exactly I'm looking for, before I start, I'm no server admin. I'm trying to help get this server up and active and I have got it all going with exception to the SQLite3. The phpinfo displays `'--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '` can somebody please advise in simple terms what to do to activate this, I've attempted a yum install.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: Duplicate - see: http://serverfault.com/questions/32982/how-do-i-enable-sqlite-on-linux-apache-php

Comment: Also on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199968/is-there-a-sqlite-entension-for-php-in-redhat-enterprise-linux-5

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS-5 you only need to install the package php53-pdo and sqlite in order to have support for sqlite3

```
# yum install php53 php53-pdo sqlite
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: For anyone wondering, on CentOS 7 it's just php and php-pdo. Though when using Nginx, one should install php-fpm instead of php.

Answer (score -1):

Redhat decided to stop supporting php-sqlite*, [but there is a good tutorial here](http://www.exteon.ro/en/articles/php/compile-extensions).

Comment: Link is dead. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: The previous link was apparently missing an s in articles:
http://www.exteon.ro/en/articles/php/compile-extensions

Answer (score -1):

The Atomic repository offers a nice, well thought out, compliant with the standard Redhat naming convention and up-to-date bunch of PHP rpms for both Centos 5 & 6. Their official site is [this](http://www.atomicorp.com) and installing the repository (not the packages) is as simple as

```
wget -O - http://www.atomicorp.com/installers/atomic | sudo bash
```

After successfully installing the repository, try

```
sudo yum update
```

to get the newest PHP packages from Atomic and then

```
sudo yum install php-sqlite
```

to get your sqlite extension installed and automatically loaded.

**Note:** Atomic offers a lot of updated packages and PHP there is on the 5.3 version. Bear that in mind if you are running 5.3-incompatible applications.